# MDX Cross joins across user defined hierarchies

Tags: mdx, cross-join

I have an MDX query like;

```
with
set [IcPiyasaCC] as 
      {
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_EDT],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_END.MRG],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_GM_YRD],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_PER.RAF],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_ULUSAL],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_PAS_MARG]
      }
member [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[IcPiyasa] as 
     aggregate([IcPiyasaCC])
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
   { 
    [Measures].[Fiili_TutarTonaj] 
   } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
   { 
     (
       [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[IcPiyasa]
    --*[DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[CostCenterKey].ALLMEMBERS
     ) 
   }
ON ROWS
```

and I can get desired output like;

```
-            Fiili_TutarTonaj
IcPiyasa           6
```

But when I try to cross join with `[DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[CostCenterKey].ALLMEMBERS` which is on same hierarchy, to get if any related "CostCenterKey"s , I get "CostCenterKey hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function." error message. How can I crossjoin them to get result like;

```
-           -             Fiili_TutarTonaj
IcPiyasa    S_EDT              1
IcPiyasa    S_END.MRG          2
IcPiyasa    S_ULUSAL           3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the new aggregated member in a different hierarchy. The cross-join will then be possible:

```
WITH
SET [IcPiyasaCC] AS 
      {
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_EDT],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_END.MRG],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_GM_YRD],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_PER.RAF],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_ULUSAL],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_PAS_MARG]
      }
MEMBER [Geography].[Geography].[All].[IcPiyasa] AS 
     AGGREGATE(
       [IcPiyasaCC],
       ([Geography].[Geography].[All])
     )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY  
    [Measures].[Fiili_TutarTonaj]  ON 0, 
NON EMPTY 
       [Geography].[Geography].[All].[IcPiyasa]
      *[DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[CostCenterKey].ALLMEMBERS
    ON 1
...
...
```

Or this:

```
WITH
SET [IcPiyasaCC] AS 
      {
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_EDT],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_END.MRG],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_GM_YRD],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_PER.RAF],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_ULUSAL],
        [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].&[S_PAS_MARG]
      }
MEMBER [Measures].[ForceName] AS 'IcPiyasaCC'
MEMBER [Geography].[Geography].[All].[IcPiyasa] AS 
     (
        [Geography].[Geography].[All]
       ,[Measures].[ForceName]
     )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY  
    [Measures].[Fiili_TutarTonaj]  ON 0, 
NON EMPTY 
       [Geography].[Geography].[All].[IcPiyasa]
      *[DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[CostCenterKey].ALLMEMBERS
    ON 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use  [DimCostCenterView].[IcPiyasa].[IcPiyasa] it gives me something like could not find '[IcPiyasa]' hierarchy when parsed (I can not translate error message exactly, it's in my native language). How sould I define the "Member"

Comment: can you add a photo of your cube structure?

Comment: where do we find `IcPiyasa` ?

Comment: There is no IcPiyasa, I am defining it on the fly :   member [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[IcPiyasa] as 
     aggregate([IcPiyasaCC]). And IcPiyasaCC is a named set, which you can see on my question how it's defined.

Comment: @bsaglamtimur I edited my contribution: you can try hosting the aggregated member in a seperate hierarchy

Comment: When I use [DimCostCenterView].[CostCenterKey].[CostCenterKey].ALLMEMBERS I get result as seen here. Http://barbaros.blob.core.windows.net/cdn/Capture_a.PNG All CostCenterKey with same value. But if I use another member from [DimCostCenterView] hierarchy like [DimCostCenterView]. **[CostCenterName].[CostCenterName]** I get expected values (measure values) (as seen here : Http://barbaros.blob.core.windows.net/cdn/Capture_b.PNG) for related CostCenterName but I do not want to show CostCenterName but CostCenterKey